# Parenthesis in variables inside IF blocks

Tags: batch-file, parentheses

In one of my scripts, I need to use variables that contain parenthesis inside `IF` statements, but either the string is missing a closing parenthesis or the script exits prematurely with `* was unexpected at this time` (not actually an asterisk), depending on the scenario.

**Example**

```
@echo off

SET path=%programFiles(x86)%
echo Perfect output: %path%
IF NOT "%path%" ==  "" (
    REM Variable is defined
    echo Broken output:  %path%
)

pause >nul
```

**Output**

```
Perfect output: C:\Program Files (x86)
Broken output:  C:\Program Files (x86
```

I think/know that this is because it thinks the closing parenthesis in `C:\Program Files (x86)` is the end of the `IF` statement and it exits before the `echo` is complete.

Is there a simple way to cirumvent this? Preferably without resorting to

1. single-line `IF` statements, as I need to run more than one line of code within them,
2. copious amounts of `GOTO`s, as it's not practical,
3. `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and using `!path!` instead of `%path%`, as I recall reading somewhere that that method doesn't work consistently across OSs.

If not, I'll happily accept the most reliable solution offered, whatever it is.

(The scenario isn't up for debate. This is just a refined, concentrated example of the problem. The structure needs to be like this, as it is in my actual script, for reasons I won't go into. It's besides the point and it'll just confuse things and distract from the actual issue.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off - you should never use the PATH variable for your own use. It is a reserved environment variable. Using it for your own purposes can break your scripts.

The simplest solution really is to use delayed expansion. As long as your platform uses CMD.EXE then you have access to delayed expansion.

But there is a relatively easy way to make it work without delayed expansion. You can use disappearing quotes. The quote exists at parse time as the name of a FOR variable while the command is parsed. It expands to nothing before execution time.

```
@echo off

SET mypath=%programFiles(x86)%
echo Perfect output: %mypath%
IF NOT "%mypath%" ==  "" (
  REM Variable is defined
  for %%^" in ("") do echo fixed output:  %%~"%mypath%%%~"
)

pause >nul
```

***EDIT - When to use delayed expansion: Response to comment***

I generally only use delayed expansion when it is needed (or more precisely, when it is advantageous). That being said, I usually find it advantageous in some portion of my batch code.

Major Advantages

- Inside a code block in order to see changes to a variable within the block
- When dereferencing the name of a variable. If a variable name is passed in as a parameter, the value of the variable can be gotten via delayed expansion: `echo !%1!`
- When using variables as arguments to search and replace or substring operations: `echo !var:%search%=%replace%!`, `echo !var:%start%,%len%!`.
- Whenever I need to expand the value and not worry about special characters within it needing escaping or quoting: `set "var=A&B" & echo !var!`

There are other methods to do the above (except the last), but delayed expansion is the easiest, most efficient (fastest to execute), and most reliable option.

Major Disadvantage

- Any FOR variable that contains `!` in its value will be corrupted when it is expanded if delayed expansion is enabled. I frequently toggle delayed expansion on and off within a FOR loop to get around the problem.
- It is not good for executing a "macro" (executing code contained within a variable value) because many important phases of command parsing take place prior to the delayed expansion. So many batch features are unavailable to "macros" that are executed via delayed expansion.

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that. Well, it was only an example anyway - I'm not actually using `%path%` in my script. Hmm, okay. Maybe I will use delayed expansion then. But it's good to know about the quote-removing `FOR` loop. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Out of further curiosity, would you recommend using delayed expansion for every instance of `%` (excluding things like `%~dp0` maybe) or just inside code blocks, in an "as and when needed" manner?

Comment: @BenHooper - Also FOR variables must be expanded using percents. See my updated answer for my recommendation.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That's great! One last thing (sorry): I'm having issues when using delayed expansion with variables that contain `^>nul`. For example: `SET pause_10=^>nul ping localhost /n 11` only works using `%pause_10%`. I've tried quite a few variations of defining the variable but I just can't get `!pause_10!` to work.

Comment: That is another disadvantage of delayed expansion - It is not very good for use as a "macro" because it occurs so late in the parse and execute scheme. Redirection cannot work when embedded within a variable that is "executed" via delayed expansion because  redirection must be parsed before delayed expansion takes place. It works with normal expansion because normal expansion takes place before the redirection is parsed.

Comment: Oh, right, okay. Well, thanks for all of your help, dbenham. I'm sure I can speak for myself and all future readers when I say that your help has been much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion is :

```
if (condition_TRUE) goto goodbye_parenthesis_BEGIN

goto goodbye_parenthesis_END  ----- line when previous condition is FALSE ----
:goodbye_parenthesis_BEGIN ----- line when previous condition is TRUE ----

...
variable treatment
...

:goodbye_parenthesis_END
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much easier to read than the `for` based trick.

Answer (score 1):

The `)` from the resolved variable in your `echo` statement is prematurely closing the `IF` block.

Ordinarily, you could fix that by escaping the `)` with `^)`, but you can't modify the environment variable to resolve to `C:\Program Files (x86^)`.

You can prevent this issue by surrounding the variable with quotes.

As a simpler example:

```
> SET bad=a)b
> IF 1 == 1 ( ECHO %bad% )
b was unexpected at this time.
> IF 1 == 1 ( ECHO "%bad%" )
"a)b"
```

Comment: You'd like to think so, wouldn't you? I only just realized that it could be misinterpreted that way, so I changed it back to what it originally was.

Comment: @BenHooper: Read more carefully.  The problem is from the **resolved** variable.  `cmd` turns that into `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and _that_ `)` closes the block.

Comment: I know. I stated that I knew that in my actual question. Anyway, the quotation marks thing isn't really a fix, as it alters the output. Say, for example, I need to use a variable in the middle of a path, I'd end up with something like `"C:\Users\userName\folder with spaces\"folder"\"`.

Comment: I don't know.  `EnableDelayedExpansion` is probably the best way to go.  I believe it's supported by Windows 2000 and later.

Comment: You could also fix this by making a new env variable with an escaped version of your path.  But I don't know offhand of any simple way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, the unescaped and unquoted closing parenthesis `)` unintentionally ends the parenthesised `if` block.

Besides escaping, quotation, [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and "disappearing quotes", there are the following further options:

1. Use a [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) meta-variable on the quoted value and remove the quotes by the [`~`-modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

   ```cmd
    @echo off

    set "PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
    echo Perfect output:  %PATH%
    if not "%PATH%" == "" (
        rem Variable is defined
        for %%P in ("%PATH%") do echo Unbroken output: %%~P
    )

    pause > nul
   ```
2. Use the [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to initiate another variable expansion phase, together with doubled (escaped) `%`-symbols:

   ```cmd
    @echo off

    set "PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
    echo Perfect output:  %PATH%
    if not "%PATH%" == "" (
        rem Variable is defined
        call echo Unbroken output: %%PATH%%
    )

    pause > nul
   ```
3. Do escaping by [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), which happens before [`^`-escaping](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) is detected:

   ```cmd
    @echo off

    set "PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
    echo Perfect output:  %PATH%
    if not "%PATH%" == "" (
        rem Variable is defined
        echo Unbroken output: %PATH:)=^)%
    )

    pause > nul
   ```