# batch file multiple actions under a if condition

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to put multiple actions under a if condition? Like this:

```
if not exist MyFolderName (
ECHO create a folder
mkdir MyFolderName
)
```

Comment: Your code block seems to work--the parentheses group multiple actions together. I don't understand your question, please elaborate.

Comment: @HaiVu, you are right. but I got error tell me format wrong before. Maybe some extra space caused that error.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `&` to join commands and execute them on the same line.

So your syntax should look like:

```
if not exist MyFolderName ECHO "Create a folder" & mkdir MyFolderName
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can use labels to jump to a section containing the commands you want to execute, for example:

```
if not exist MyFolderName GOTO DOFILESTUFF
:AFTER
...
EXIT

:DOFILESTUFF
ECHO "Create a folder"
mkdir MyFolderName
GOTO AFTER
```

Answer (score 0):

'&' operator works perfectly as mjgpy3 explained.
 Also, We can add more then 2 statement using &. I have checked with 3 ststement and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!

Check the link below, but remember: you must write the code exactly as the example is shown (all the spaces and parentheses).

[Can I have an IF block in DOS batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983508/can-i-have-an-if-block-in-dos-batch-file)

You can nest other if statements inside if statements, as long as you follow the example. And it works without `else` too.