# File keeps getting deleted

Tags: batch-file

I am having trouble with a batch program of mine where I have 2 `if` statements where one of them allows the user to add a comment to the log file and the other `if` statement deletes the log file altogther.

It is up to the user which option they choose, but when I run the file it seems to delete my log file even if I type in option 1 to add a comment to the log file and not delete it.

```
echo loggedTime = %time% %date%>> log.txt

REM This is for the 2 scenarios the user has to choose from

echo Please make your choice:

set /p choice1=

REM This takes the user's input and adds it to the end of the text file

IF %choice1%== 1 echo Please enter your comment:

set /p comment=

echo %comment%>> log.txt

REM this deletes the log file altogether

IF %choice1%== 2 echo The log file is being deleted

cd C:\Users\.....

del log.txt
```

Comment: you fail to make use of script breaks or If a == b (command) Else (Command) structuring in your code to prevent the script continuing to the next line.

Comment: You really should consider changing your first line and possibly the echoing of their comment too. You may have an issue, if the last character in either `%date%`, _(very likely)_, or `%comment%`, _(possible)_, is a digit, this could then become an unwanted redirection handle, and not output as you intended to the log file.

Comment: so you are worried, a filter would prove you plagiarized from your own code? But you don't worry it would find the answers (which are not by you) with no hint that they're based on your code? Strange thinking. Leave the code in your question to prove it's your idea and you just had a little problem with it. Besides that, your code is now [property of  Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing)

Comment: (PS: "Deleting" your question won't help either, because that only hides the page from "normal" users. The question will stay in the Stack Overflow database and chances are good, a filter will find it nevertheless)

Answer (score 0):

The command interpreter reads every line in the script unless you structure your script in a way that prevents this.

This most common ways of achieving this is through the use of code blocks (Lines of code contained within parentheses) and Labels to 'skip' lines.
When taking user input, through set /p, you need a method to validate it, and return for new input if the input doesn't match the Conditional tests your using.

There is a better way still to achieve all of these points, and thats combining the `Choice` Command with Labels in the form of subroutines as follows:

```
@Echo off
Goto :main
REM Script break created by the label Jump

REM Subroutines
:Choice[1]
    Echo(loggedTime = [%time% %date%]>>"%temp%\Mylog.txt"
    set /p comment=Comment:
    echo("%comment%">>"%temp%\Mylog.txt"
    Exit /B
:Choice[2]
    del "%temp%\Mylog.txt"
    Exit /B
:Choice[3]
    IF exist "%temp%\Mylog.txt" (TYPE "%temp%\Mylog.txt")
    Exit /B

REM main body of the script
:main
REM /N : Hide options prompt
REM /C : Define options (options will be assigned errorlevel according to occurance after /C switch)
REM /M "prompt string" : Define Custom prompt for the choice
    CHOICE /N /C cdv /M "add (C)omment (D)elete Log (V)iew Log"
REM Calls the selected subroutine. Exit /B within the Subroutine resumes the script from after the call
    CALL :Choice[%errorlevel%]
    pause
    Exit /B
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies with how DOS …err, CMD, deals with IF/ELSE blocks. The short form is, if an IF clause is resolved as true, the rest of the line is executed, otherwise it is skipped. THEN, execution proceeds to the next line, whether or not the IF was true or false.

So, both your `set /p choice1=` and `del log.txt` lines are being executed each time. I modified your script a bit as follows to be sure of this:

```
@ECHO OFF

echo loggedTime = %time% %date%>> log.txt

REM This is for the 2 scenarios the user has to choose from

echo Please make your choice:

set /p choice1=

ECHO #%choice1%#

REM This takes the user's input and adds it to the end of the text file

IF %choice1%== 1 echo Please enter your comment:

set /p comment=

ECHO #%comment%#

echo %comment%>> log.txt

REM this deletes the log file altogether

IF %choice1%== 2 echo The log file is being deleted

del log.txt
```

The following posts will explain a bit more, and show how to deal with multiple conditional statements:

- [Can I have an IF block in DOS batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983508/can-i-have-an-if-block-in-dos-batch-file)
- [batch file multiple actions under a if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321822/batch-file-multiple-actions-under-a-if-condition/12321880)

Comment: This does not solve the users problem.  The Delete will still be executed if the user enters a 1.