# #Del fileName (but file is not available, then will it process further or Stop )?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

need to delete a file and then process further.

```
del file.html

echo  ^<center^>^<a href="abc.html"^>ABC^</a^>^</center^> >> file.html
......
echo  ^<center^>^<a href="xyz.com"^>XYZ^</a^>^</center^> >> file.html
```

at first time i got this message `Could Not Find C:\Users\file.html` but processed further to write into the file. I want to know, can it stop processing further at any stage if the file is not found to delete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this question - [Can I have an IF block in DOS batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983508/can-i-have-an-if-block-in-dos-batch-file) - DOS can do if branching via

```
if <statement> (
    do something
) else (
    do something else
)
```

And then from [this MS Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/65994) you can use `EXIST` and `NOT EXIST` with files. So my guess would be:

```
if EXIST file.html del file.html
```

Just by the bye, if you wanted to do this in bash (via Cygwin on Windows), it is rather easier as bash has more support for this stuff than DOS:

```
f="file.html";
if [ -e "$f" ] ; then 
    rm "$f";
fi
```

You appear to be appending things to the file, line by line. If there is no processing going on in these lines, you can just [concatenate them using copy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69575):

```
copy chunkA.html+chunkB.html+chunkD.html file.html
```

That offers the significant benefit that you separate the files containing the data from the script that is stitching them together.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file exists first, and proceed with your other commands only if it does.

```
if exist file.html (
del file.html
echo  ^<center^>^<a href="abc.html"^>ABC^</a^>^</center^> >> file.html
echo  ^<center^>^<a href="xyz.com"^>XYZ^</a^>^</center^> >> file.html
)
```

Comment: I think the Q is describing a guard before the deletion command to only run it if the file exists, i.e. so that it doesn't error each time if the file doesn't exist. So I think you need to move the closing bracket to after the del line.