# Nested IF Statement, unexpected error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, nested-if

I have created a nested if statement that just performs very simple tasks. Here is the code below:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ANS=%1
IF "%ANS%"=="" ( ECHO You Entered Nothing
  )
  IF /i %ANS%==Y ( ECHO You entered Yes
    )
    IF /i %ANS%==N ( ECHO You entered NO
      )
      IF %ANS%==? ( ECHO I am confused
        )
```

My problem is that when "%ANS%"=="" i get a "( was unexpected at this time" after echoing the message i have provided. Everything else works as planned but i am not sure why i am getting this message.

Comment: Why do you think those are nested if statements? Also, check out the correct syntax for an if-else statement in batch [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4983613/63733) - the echo statement should be on a new line.

Comment: Both ways have the same results. Everything works besides the "%ans"=="" generating the "( was unexpected at this time."

Answer (score 1):

The error message comes from your second `IF`.
If %1 is empty, your first `IF` gives you "You entered nothing" as intended.
Then the second `IF`line translates to

```
IF /i ==Y ( ECHO You entered YES
```

(because %ANS% is empty)

Therefore you get a "( was unexpected at this time).

To correct this, write

```
IF /i "%ANS%"=="Y" ( ECHO You entered Yes
```

Comment: Thank you, adding a few quotes here and there solved the problem.

Comment: Yes. The reason is that the entire block of IF statements is parsed in one pass, and all syntax must be correct, even if it never gets executed. The later IF statements become invalid if the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This has elements that protect it from `spaces` and `duoble quotes` and `&` characters.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "ANS=%~1"
IF "%ANS%"==""     ( ECHO You Entered Nothing  )
IF /i "%ANS%"=="Y" ( ECHO You entered Yes      )
IF /i "%ANS%"=="N" ( ECHO You entered NO       )
IF "%ANS%"=="?"    ( ECHO I am confused        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ... it works perfectly

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ANS="%1"
IF %ANS%=="" ( ECHO You Entered Nothing
  )
  IF /i %ANS%=="Y" ( ECHO You entered Yes
    )
    IF /i %ANS%=="N" ( ECHO You entered NO
      )
      IF %ANS%=="?" ( ECHO I am confused
        )
```