# How do you do if questions in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hay i try to make a few if statements in bash, but i can´t get it to work its many examples how to do it here in stackoverflow but i can´t find any that work for me

I have try here "if (%%F = "\A" or %%F == "\B") (" to check if %%F contain "\A" or "\B" folder then continue whit the loop else jump to next

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
  set PREFIX=%CD:~0,-1%
) else (
  set PREFIX=%CD%
)

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /s/b') do (

  if (%%F = "\A" or %%F == "\B") (
    set N=%%~dpF%%~nF
    set N=!N:%PREFIX%=!

    if not "!N:~1,4!" == "root" (
      set N=%PREFIX%\root!N!

      if not exist "!N!" (
        mkdir "!N!"
      )
    )
  )
)

pause
```

/Mvh Whiskey

Comment: Related: [Can I have an IF block in DOS batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983508/can-i-have-an-if-block-in-dos-batch-file/)

Answer (score 0):

if [ - statements]
then dothisandthat
fi

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Do you really mean "bash" (Linux) or batch (Windows)?

Comment: Sorry its batch, the code shows that :=) And i don´t look for examples o look after someone that can get it work as i have try whit 20 different things nothing works, also in bash this would not be any problem it alot more easy then batch is \Whiskey

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a equallity operator to test if a string can be found inside another.

String replacements can be problematic with delayed expansion enabled and paths/file names with exclamation marks in them.

It is easier to enumerate the relative paths to the files (`xcopy` is used to only list the files), filter out the non required elements inside "root" folder, filter to only retrieve the files inside the required folders and then for the remaining files ....

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("%cd%\root") do set "root=%%~fa"

    for /f "tokens=* delims=.\" %%a in (
        'xcopy . "%temp%\%random%%random%" /s /l /i ^
        ^| findstr /lvi /c:".\\root\\" ^
        ^| findstr /ri  /c:"\\[a-z]\\.*"'
    ) do for %%b in ("::\%%a") do (
        if not exist "%root%%%~pb%%~nb" echo mkdir "%root%%%~pb%%~nb"
    )

    pause
```

Comment: That don´t work as i espect, and not work at all, look what my script does, you copy stuff to the actully place where it allredy is i only create folders your looks like it try to create files \Whiskey

Comment: actully everything is fine espect that you don´t create folders whitout ext, you copy over the files check and everything is fine

Comment: Not sure why you use xcopy the code i have was just fine, but it does what i asked for thanks alot!

Comment: @Whiskey, to avoid prefix removal. `xcopy /l` list what files will copy, and if the source does not include drive/path, the list shows relative paths. The "problem" with your code raises when paths/filenames include exclamation marks. Can be handled, but needs more code to do the same that the `xcopy` will do

Comment: I try to create this to make from A-Z but it only comes to C why?

Comment: @Whiskey, code updated to filter folders `\a\` to `\z\`. Is this the problem?