# How to run multiple commands in if condition in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to run multiple commands in if condition in batch file.

I have tried below code but its not working for me.

```
IF not exist %directoryPath% (echo Invalid directory. goto :InvalidDirectory) ELSE (echo Sencha app build development started..)
```

**Code:**

```
:EnterDirectory
echo Enter your project directory
set /P directoryPath=
IF exist %directoryPath% (goto :init) ELSE (goto :InvalidDirectory)

:InvalidDirectory
echo This directory does not exists. 
(goto :EnterDirectory)

:init
IF not exist %directoryPath% (goto :InvalidDirectory) ELSE (echo Sencha app build development started..)
```

Comment: `echo Invalid directory.`[`&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)`goto :InvalidDirectory`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I have an IF block in DOS batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983508/can-i-have-an-if-block-in-dos-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using  batchfiles, don't try to do everything in one line. That makes your script unreadable and might even give you wrong/unexpected results, when you don't pay enough attention to the syntax (which easily happens). This kind of failures is hard to troubleshoot. Split it into several lines (ideally one command per line):

```
IF not exist %directoryPath% (
  echo Invalid directory.
  goto :InvalidDirectory
) ELSE (
  echo Sencha app build development started..
)
```

If you insist on doing it in one line, `&` is the proper way to chain two commands:

```
IF not exist %directoryPath% (echo Invalid directory. & goto :InvalidDirectory) ELSE (echo Sencha app build development started..)
```

Comment: I would recommend that `%directoryPath%` has a trailing backslash to ensure that it's checking for the existence of a directory, as opposed to a file.